# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value ( before: "Hello Firebase", after: textView.text

Tags: swift, swift3, option-type

I'm making a database with firebase.

```
@IBAction func addPost(_ sender: Any) {

    // Post the data to firebase
    ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue("Hello Firebase")

    // Dismiss the popover
    presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The above code is working correctly and [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6c51.png)

and I change it to the code below:

```
@IBAction func addPost(_ sender: Any) {

    // Post the data to firebase
    ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(textView.text)

    // Dismiss the popover
    presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

after changing it I get:

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" 
>   error occurred....

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your `textView` IBOutlet is probably disconnected.

Comment: thank you..you are right